# NTLM authentification is not working in Apache/PHP

Tags: php, apache

So, what's the story

I want to enable NTLM auth in Apache and already installed ntlm library (mod_auth_ntlm), installed necessary VS redistributable and placed following strings to httpd.conf

```
LoadModule auth_ntlm_module modules/mod_authn_ntlm.so


<Location /test >
     AuthType NTLM
     NTLMAuth on
     NTLMAuthoritative on
     NTLMOfferBasic off
    <RequireAll>
        <RequireAny>
            Require valid-user
        </RequireAny>
    </RequireAll>
</Location>
```

Starting phpinfo - and there is no variables like REMOTE_USER, but ntlm library is successfully loaded

Any folder on web-server is accessible except /test folder - it just returns error 500
Apache error.log has following strings:

```
[Wed Feb 24 14:54:46.231132 2016] [authn_core:error] [pid 668:tid 1776] [client 10.16.66.19:53872] AH01796: AuthType NTLM configured without corresponding module
```

So, what's the catch? Any other possibilities?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found!

Still, it's not NTLM library, but SSPI (mod-authn-sspi)

1. Download correct version of SSPI library (in case of Apache 2.4 it should be mod_authnz_sspi)
2. Unzip and put .so file into Apache /modules directory
3. Edit httpd.conf

`LoadModule authnz_sspi_module modules/mod_authnz_sspi.so
<Directory "/test"> 
AllowOverride None 
Options None 
Order allow,deny 
Allow from all 
AuthType SSPI 
SSPIAuth On 
SSPIAuthoritative On 
SSPIDomain KL
Require valid-user 
</Directory>`

4. Create directory /test in your www folder (/test is just exemplary folder) and place following .htaccess file

`AuthName "authoriz"
AuthType SSPI
SSPIAuth On
SSPIAuthoritative On
require valid-user`

Of course, you can change AuthName

5. Try following php code in the /test directory

`<?php
$cred = explode('\\',$_SERVER['REMOTE_USER']);
if (count($cred) == 1) array_unshift($cred, "(no domain info - perhaps SSPIOmitDomain is On)");
list($domain, $user) = $cred;
echo "You appear to be user <B>$user</B><BR/>";
echo "logged into the Windows NT domain <B>$domain</B>";
?>`

Should work!